# How to convert UnityScript to C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Can somebody try to convert this script into a 2D C# script?

```
public var explosionStrength : float = 10.0f;

function OnTriggerEnter (target_ : Collider)
{
    var forceVec : Vector3 = -target_.rigidbody.velocity.normalized * explosionStrength;
    target_.rigidbody.AddForce(forceVec,ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting from JS to C# isn't that hard. :)

Here, I'll do a couple for you.  You should be able to figure out the rest.

```
//original JS
public var explosionStrength : float

//new C#
public float explosionStrength
```

Or

```
//original JS
function OnTriggerEnter (target_ : Collider)

//new C#
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider target_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go :) If you look into it it really is simple :)

```
public float explosionStrength = 10.0f;

 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider target_){
 Vector3 forceVec = -target_.rigidbody.velocity.normalized * explosionStrength;
 target_.rigidbody.AddForce(forceVec,ForceMode.Acceleration);
 }
```

Comment: thank you fro replying but nothings really happening

Comment: That is another matter. Post another question about what do you want to achieve.